# Can i run a web server with php support on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspbian, raspbmc, operating-systems

I want to use the Raspberry Pi as a web hosting device. I want to run **php server**. Is it posible? If so how?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=webserver+raspberry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it posible?

Yes.

> If so how?

The most common approach is probably the [LAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29) stack (minus the "M" if you don't need an SQL server).  There's tons and tons of information, books, etc. available about this.

There's nothing special about the raspberry pi in this context; raspbian is a normal linux distribution, so you can follow normal instructions for using Apache (aka. `httpd`) on Linux in general.  You don't have to look for anything pi specific.<sup>1</sup>

There are other HTTP servers besides Apache you can use PHP with;  e.g. [Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration#PHP_via_FastCGI).

<sup>1</sup> So, questions about the topic are best off in a more general forum:

- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) PHP programming questions.
- [Super User](https://superuser.com/) Apache/Nginx/server questions.
- [Unix & Linux Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) Linux questions, including apache/nginx/etc configuration.